# IDE for picoblaze with KCPSM3 instruction set

Tags: assembly, ide, xilinx

the pblazeIDE is no longer available for download

see related discussion

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Processor-System-Design/PicoBlaze/td-p/748483

is there another assembly IDE that supports the KCPSM3 instruction set, and allows single step and register value monitor?  I tried it with intel FPGA monitor program but it doesn't support it.

I've been searching and there is this , but it is password protected 
http://www.sourcecodeprojects.com/downloadkey=weaf&f=PBlazeIDE+software&r=&u=1926134

Comment: There is [OPBASM](https://github.com/kevinpt/opbasm) from Kevin. It's a PicoBlaze compiler written in Python supporting KCPSM3 and KCPSM6.

Comment: @Paebbels i am using DOSBox 0.74 for compilation, need an IDE which allows me to single step and view reg values like pblazeIDE or intel FPGA monitor program. Your suggestion doesn't appear to have those features.

Comment: You can use an ILA to observer what's going on in you KCPSM, If you need single-stepping, then your development process is not in a good shape ...

Comment: @Paebbels i'm a student, I don't expect it to be in good shape. That's why I need single stepping so I can see develop an intuition and learn to debug.

Comment: OPBASM comes with an integrated simulator: [OPBSIM](http://kevinpt.github.io/opbasm/rst/opbsim.html)

Comment: Try FIDEX IDE...

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on that thing but is a very old/useful stuff.

You can download it directly from [here](https://www.avnet.com/opasdata/d120001/medias/common/7/Avnet-AES-S6IVK-LX150T-G-FMCDVI_DVI_Pass_Through_Demo_ISE_Design_Suite_12_2.zip).

It is a design reference tutorial but in `FMCDVI_DVI_Pass_Through_Demo_12_2_20100921/verilog/rtl/picoblaze` directory, you can find pblazeIDE executable (for winXP x86).

Also if you want to make a picoblaze module maybe you should take a look to [this](https://github.com/kevinpt/opbasm) and [this](https://kevinpt.github.io/opbasm/rst/tutorial.html). First one is a open picoblaze compiler for linux and last one is for programming reference.